# NodeJs create dynamic mySql table based on CSV input

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, csv

I'm trying to build an application which does the following (simplified):

1. Allow the user to select a CSV file
2. Upload that CSV to NodeJS server
3. Parse the file and create array of rows (with headers)
4. Generate dynamic "Create Table" sql based on the column headers in the csv, but also detect the datatype (the column names, datatypes etc will be different every time)
5. Insert the csv data into the newly created table

Its step 4 I'm having trouble with. Is there a way to scan an array of data elements and determine what the datatype should be?

I've looked at Papa Parse and csv-parse but neither do what I need. Papa Parse comes close though, but it converts each array element separately and doesn't pick up dates.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you run a full file scan, it will be difficult to guess the exact types.

Another problem is handling errors in input files, eg the number in the column, which should be stored a date.

Further: the insurance number (or account number) is a number, but in the database should be stored as a string.

**I suggest you a method straight from Big Data Analysis.**

Run the entire process in 3 stages: first create an intermediate table, where each column will be of type `Text` and import data into it using mysq: [`LOAD DATA INFILE ...`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)

Conduct a preliminary analysis based on the user's previous choices, column names, content analysis and display for user a "wizard" of the table. (Or skip display wizard)

The analysis should include the calculation of the shortest, longest, average and most common lengths (eg first 100 rows contains long string who is error message: `Some date for some proces isn't provided` and other are valid date); variety of values (gender, country, other "dictionary" values); random content analysis (detection dates and numbers)

At the end you can use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`, change column type (don't forget allow to `NULL` for convert error) or line by line convert and filtering operation.

***//edit***

Eh, I thought your files had a few GB. Loading large files in memory does not make sense.

Of course, you can use a library to read CSV and analyze it in memory instead of a temporary table in MySQL. But you will not avoid content analysis anyway. There is nothing to hide - automatic analysis without advanced AI systems works on average.

If you've found something that even detects data types a bit, you can build on it. Helpful also, I can be a [tablesorter parsers](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/tree/master/js/parsers).

Comment: Not a solution to the problem, I need the full process to happen within Nodejs

Comment: You can do the whole process in the node, but it does not change the fact that you are waiting for analysis and finding a solution to the problems that I mentioned. (BTW: Check the update.)

Answer (score 0):

if you still looking for answer, i would recommend npm csv parser packages such as `const parse = require('csv-parse')` , it is simply easy, first of all you have to get csv file data and parse it through csv parser function, then loop through your data and put it in an object to use it in sql query..